# Simplification of Biot-Savart law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I've come across the formula $B=\frac{kI}{d}$ for the magnetic field around a wire. However, I cannot find this online. I believe it is some simplification of the Biot-Savart law. If this is the case, what assumptions does this formula make?

**Notation:** Here $I$ denotes current, $d$ denotes the distance from a current carrying wire, $k$ is some constant, $B$ represents the strength of the magnetic field.

Comment: It would be great if you specify what k, I and d are, even if they seem implied

Comment: Difficult to say since the variables are not defined, but it is probably the Ampere Law applied to a loop of radius $d$ around the wire with current $I$. See e.g.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/291378/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112131/226902

Comment: @Quillo Why do those formulas seems much more complicated?

Comment: Related : [A generalization of the Biot-Savart law for a number  n  of wires with  n≥3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550087/a-generalization-of-the-biot-savart-law-for-a-number-n-of-wires-with-n-geq-3) and [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge).

Comment: @QuinGardinerBax - They seem complicated because they are in integral form.. but for some geometries the integral is trivial and you obtain your simple formula. I have added an answer with the main idea (plus links for the vector calculus details).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Ampere's circuital law for an infinitely long wire & wire of given length](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/using-amperes-circuital-law-for-an-infinitely-long-wire-wire-of-given-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Biot-Savart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law) and [Ampere's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law) are related (you can easily link the two via [Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#Maxwell%27s_equations)), see:

- [Ampère's law vs Biot Savart law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/291378/226902)
- [What is the difference between Biot-Savart law and Ampere's law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112131/226902)

Now, consider Ampere's law applied to a loop $\gamma$ that embraces a wire carrying current $I$,

$$\oint_\gamma \mathbf B\cdot d\mathbf s = \mu_0 I \, .$$

The integral is a [line integral of the vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field) $\mathbf B$ along the path $\gamma$. If you choose $\gamma$ to be a circle of radius $d$ in a plane orthogonal to the wire (the wire being at the centre of the circle $\gamma$), the above integral is trivial and is equivalent to

$$
(2 \pi d) B  = \mu_0 I
$$

where $B$ is the magnitude of the magnetic field at distance $d$ from the wire (we are using the symmetry of the problem to simplify the calculation, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/677949/226902) for the details!). The above relation is equivalent to $B=kI/d$, where the constant $k$ depends on the units used (SI, cgs, Gauss...). In this case $k =\mu_0/(2 \pi) $ ([SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_electromagnetism_units)).

**Edit:** This post is closely related to/possible duplicate of [Magnetic field of a long straight wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/674299/226902), [Using Ampere's circuital law for an infinitely long wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14078/226902), [How can we apply Ampère's circuital law in a wire?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241476/226902), [Ampère's law from Biot-Savart law for linear currents](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227477/226902) (and [its duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228328/226902)).